# Freeing Nested Pointers and setting to NULL in C

Tags: c, security

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct sample {
 void* data;
}sample_t;


int main()
{
    printf("Hello world!\n");
    sample_t* samplestruct = (sample_t*) malloc(sizeof(sample_t));
    samplestruct->data = (void*) malloc(10);

    free(samplestruct->data);    
    free(samplestruct);    
    samplestruct->data = NULL;    
    samplestruct = NULL;    

    return 0;
}
```

In the above code, I free both 'samplestruct->data' and 'samplestruct' and then setting both of them to NULL, in the order I free. Right now, the code is not crashing the application. Is there any problem with the code? Can this be exploited in any ways (I mean security-wise)?

Comment: you can't use `samplestruct` after being freed

Comment: Yes, I agree with the point: " 'samplestruct' is a dangling pointer once freed, and we can't use" I am trying to understand how hackers would exploit these kind of bugs in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Traditionally, implementations of `free` did not alter the free'd memory until you call `malloc` the next time. This is still true on some platforms (which might be the reason why your code does not crash) but can't and shouldn't be relied on. Even if it is so, in a multi-threaded application, the memory just free'd might have been allocated by a different thread inbetween call to `free` and usage. In general, such a race condition could be used by an attacker to make your pointer point to other data, possibly data controlled by the attacker.

Do not write code like the code in your question.

Comment: Thanks.. I am writing this kind of code :) .. I am checking how this could be made exploitable...